# Debugging JSP on a remote Tomcat server from Eclipse + Javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, jsp

I'm working on legacy code for a J2EE application which is installed on my company's DEV server. I use eclipse to debug the JSP by activating debugging on the server's JVM and binding my workstation's eclipse to it.
So far everything worked well, but now I've got to debug some Javascript code from those pages. I wish I could do it directly form eclipse as well, instead of having to find the code form within firebug and debugging is only form firebug.
Is there a way to bind eclipse to my local firefox copy and debug javascript from within eclipse? I heard there were some solutions that allowed javascript debugging, but with this legacy code I'm also bound to certain browser version, so I'm stuck with firefox 2 and IE6.

Hope anyone can lighten the path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with debugging in Firebug?

Comment: Mainly because I would like to place breakpoints and do all the debugging from a single source, instead of mixing multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the JSDT here: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/debug/.